# Make only some query fields editable

Tags: sql, ms-access, subform

I have a junction table (FTE) that links two tables "Employees" and "ProjectList", and two other fields of the junction table("Hours" and "Entry Date"). I have a form where the employee can enter his hours by selecting a project (his name is automatically populated using his windows login) in a list from the ProjectList table and also enter the date.
On that form I also  have a sub form that shows the past entries ( only for the person logged in) in the junction table. The query to populate that subform is

```
SELECT Employees.[Full Name], ProjectList.ProjectName, FTE.Hours, FTE.[Entry Date]
FROM ProjectList INNER JOIN (FTE INNER JOIN Employees ON FTE.EmployeeID = Employees.ID) ON 
ProjectList.ID = FTE.ProjectID
WHERE (((FTE.EmployeeID)=[Forms]![HoursLog]![txb_EmployeeID]));
```

So here is my issue: when the employee goes into the subform query and changes the name or project in the subquery table, it actually changes the name or project name in the original Employees and ProjectList tables and not only in the junction table. I would like the person to be able to change the date and hours if they made a mistake but not influence" the original Employees and ProjectList  tables.
As the subfrm is populated by a query, is it possible to make only the date and hours editable. Or do I have to completely change the way the form is designed ?

Answer (score 2):

If you use a form, the proper way is, of course, to set Locked to True or Enabled to False on the controls you don't want to be editable.

However, if you are using the query directly, you can easily disable editing by making the field a calculated one, e.g. for a text field:

```
SELECT Employees.[Full Name], ProjectList.ProjectName + '' As ProjectName, FTE.Hours, FTE.[Entry Date]
FROM ProjectList INNER JOIN (FTE INNER JOIN Employees ON FTE.EmployeeID = Employees.ID) ON 
ProjectList.ID = FTE.ProjectID
WHERE (((FTE.EmployeeID)=[Forms]![HoursLog]![txb_EmployeeID]));
```

For a numeric field, you could increment it by 0. If you don't know the field type, you can also use `IIF`: `IIF(True, ProjectList.ProjectName, ProjectList.ProjectName) As ProjectName`

Comment: This worked ! but I was just wondering once I have multiple people choosing a project, why if one person changes the name of the project in it's record it changes the name of the project in the original list ? Does that have something to do with my table relationships ? I'm missing something here.

Comment: You're retrieving the project name from the projectlist table, so that's where it's changed when a user makes changes, it's as simple as that.